# Failed to import new Gradle project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I got the error when i create a new Project using android studio.
below i attached a screenshots of error message..[image]
I am using windows 7 (64 bit)
Please help me.

Comment: go to File --> Settings --> click option-->Gradle location.go to Gradle download site, then download a local distribution of Gradle and check the Gradle location t dat directory.

Comment: but i create a new project

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609666/could-not-fetch-model-of-type-ideaproject-using-gradle-installation)

Comment: @siddharth lele and Eng.Fouad please see the asked question date

Comment: @HardikNadiyapara: And you are telling that to me because?? I haven't marked it as a duplicate. I merely added a tag to your question mate!!

Comment: @Siddharth Lele if i asked a question one day before then what is the requirement of editing it??

Comment: @HardikNadiyapara: And how did me adding the tag affect your question? Besides adding a little clarity to what the question stands for! That is the whole point of tags isn't it? The chronology of your question has **absolutely** nothing to do with tags! And if you feel differently you might consider reading [What are tags, and how should I use them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Mine had this same error but had a 'not enough memory' error within it I added "-XX:MaxHeapSize=256m" to the JVM options in the project creation config (last step) and this fixed it

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I also had an issue downloading `gradle` through `AndroidStudio`. I tried the following.

1. Go to your `AndroidStudio` directory where you installed your studio Like `D:\User\AndroidStudio`
2. In `AndroidStudio` go to `\AndroidStudio\plugins\gradle\lib` and copy `gradle.jar`
3. Paste `gradle.jar` file in `\AndroidStudio\lib` directory.
4. Download gradle directly from [Gradle](http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip)
5. Copy the contents of `gradle-1.6-bin.zip` - After extracting zip file - `(bin, media, init.d, lib folders)` to `\AndroidStudio\plugins\gradle`
6. Restart `AndroidStudio`

*** Updated Answer ***

And after following all the steps listed above, if it is not working, Kindly check below things.

1) Please delete `.gradle` folder from your user like `C:\Document and Settings\AndroidUser\***\.gradle`

2) You can check your `HTTP Proxy` in `Settings`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: after completion of step provided by you, i create new project and it throws an error "org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.settings.GradleSettings cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.settings.GradleSettings"

Comment: @Hardik Nadiyapara, I had the same problem as you after following these instructions. After deleting gradle.jar from \AndroidStudio\lib (the one you pasted in step 3) it works.

Comment: @HardikNadiyapara As `AndroidStudio` is in early preview access version, you can do two things 1) Please delete `.gradle` folder from your user like `C:\Document and Settings\AndroidUser\***\.gradle` or 2) You can check your `HTTP Proxy Settings`.

Comment: @Abhan Thanks it help me a lot.and one more things can you edit you answer for helping others..

Comment: @Rotem if I delete the .jar file from \AndroidStudio\lib, when I open AndroidStudio it tells me that I have no gradle plugin installed and other plugins may not work (for dependecies reason), and I can see only Maven as option for the import...

Comment: Also be sure that you don't have a GRADLE_HOME environment variable set to another (older) installation of gradle. This will cause all kinds of errors.

Comment: I did the steps above but I am still receiving the same error as @HardikNadiyapara

Comment: @SiKni8 Hi, Google recently released newer version of Android Studio with some bug fixes. You can download that one. Thanks.

Comment: It was just too much for configuration and although setting up Eclipse takes twice as long but the process is much simpler. Until AS get out of Early Preview build, I will stick to Eclipse. Thanks @Abhan

Comment: @SiKni8 You should follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17612960/1235074

Comment: Nope! Made things more ugly and worse. This IDE is assigned for the biggest and most epic fail I have ever seen.

Comment: @MartinPfeffer They are fixing bugs with each release. You should always tuned with the latest. I used it earlier and after that so many versions are released.

Answer (score 28):

In my case, it was sufficient to specify the location of the Gradle distribution included with Android Studio when requested.

On a mac, it was: `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.2.1` 
On Linux, it can be generalized to `{android-studio-root}/grade/gradle-{version}`

Answer (score 10):

1. First Create a New Project "`your_project`"
2. When the above stated error appears click `ok`
3. Now go to `IMPORT-> "your_project "` and follow the instruction
4. Your Project Is Created

Comment: if i do that, my files don't list at all!

Answer (score 4):

Download [gradle](http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip), and replace it with the file
 `gradle-1.6-bin.zip` 
located at:
`C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.6-bin\<some_hash_key>\`

Answer (score 2):

If Android Studio offers you to choose home folder for gradle, just choose "Use customizable gradle". Then, if you see only gradle files, but no classes and resources - click on "Synchronize gradle" and it will be alrigth. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

For me, this issue only occurs when using a proxy server.
If you specify a proxy server in the settings, everything is working fine for me.
You can specify a proxy server by File->Settings->HTTP Proxy

Answer (score 1):

If you using ubuntu behind a proxy, in my case I'm using ctlm, you must change the jetbrains' proxy setting in /Home/UserName/.AndroidStudioPreview/config/options/other.xml

```
<option name="USE_HTTP_PROXY" value="true" />
<option name="PROXY_HOST" value="localhost" />
<option name="PROXY_PORT" value="8080" />
```

This is my configuration I don't need autentificated user.

bests Regards

Comment: And in Windows it's in the C:\Users directory

Comment: And this is the only way it worked for me. not studio.properties, not idea. properties, no -Dhttp.proxy. Nothing. Only this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem I think because our internet set-up blocked access to https://dl-ssl.google.com site.I resolved in by downloading gradle 1.6 zip then extracted it in some folder.go to File --> Settings --> click option-->Gradle ,the check use local gradle distribution and point it to the extracted directory eg C:\android-studio\plugins\gradle\gradle-1.6-bin\gradle-1.6  Then it was okay

Answer (score 0):

We have to change the android sdk source in the project settings to our sdk where we have installed the android build tools.

I had the same issue and by doing this, it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your proxy setting for gradle. If it still fails after set the HTTP Proxy in setting menu, you may add `gradle.properties` as following.

First, go to the project directory. (By default-for Windows-, projects will be created to `{user}\AndroidStudioProjects\{ProjectName}`). 
And then create gradle.properties file as below.

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

you can also refer to the **[User's guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.6/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties)**.

Comment: I have `gradle-wrapper.jar` and `gradle-wrapper.properties` under the `wrapper` folder. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

While importing the project I specified the location of the Gradle distribution.

On Windows 7 it was here:

```
C:\Program Files\Android-Studio\gradle\gradle-2.2.1
```