# I cannot open new project on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to open new project on the Android Studio and it gives me this error

[image]
what should i do? i didnwt get it

Comment: try to download the grible again. Tomorrow moring I had tried twice before I can get it

Comment: have you followed the steps given to migrate the eclipse project to android studio..?

Comment: @Jeet i did not try to add a project from eclipse i'm trying to open new one on android studio

Comment: I was having the same problem and after spending few hours, I found this link: [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586674/failed-to-import-new-gradle-project-in-android-studio/16620500#16620500) I followed all the listed steps and now I am able to create a project very smoothly. I hope this can help you.