# Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle installation

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I've downloaded and installed Android Studio with all the required dependencies such as JDK 1.7 and Gradle 1.6. I am able to import the projects and modules quite comfortably in  Studio, but when I try to create a new project I am getting errors like this:

[image]

Since this is the new born IDE I couldn't find much details on this, except for [**this**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55346) and [**this**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55324). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to import new Gradle project in android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586674/failed-to-import-new-gradle-project-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After to pass much time trying to resolve this, i reached a solution :

Are you using "Windows Version" of AS ?

Please follow these steps :

```
1 - Install the last version of JDK with respective JAVA_HOME variable.

2 - Download and Install Gradle1.6 with respective GRADLE_HOME variable,
```

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#installation.

```
2 - Delete these folders:

    C:\Users\youruser\.AndroidStudioPreview
    C:\Users\youruser\.android
    C:\Users\youruser\.gradle

3 - Reopen Android Studio

Now probably it will works
```

There are a lot of bugs in "Early Access Preview"....

Comment: Looks like the latest patch did not work too. Thanks for the work around.

Comment: Tried this, but it didn't work for me. I don't have the exact same situation though I do have the same "Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle installation" with gradle 1.6. This is with a project I created in Android Studio.

Comment: Surely deleting .android is a bad idea since this is where all your emulator profiles are?

Comment: I up voted this one too soon, ended up running into the error after all :(

Answer (score 2):

The error dialog mentions Gradle 1.4

Android Studio requires the Gradle plugin 0.4 which requires Gradle 1.6

Comment: Ok. i've found the solution here. rather than downloading and unzipping the gradle package manually, i've leave it on android-studio. so when you create a new project for the very first time after installing android-studio, it will automatically download all the gradle dependency and install it for you. so you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the environment variable and folder location stuff suggested, also made sure I had the latest version of Gradle, but that made no improvement. Then I ran Android Studio using an admin account, at which point all the errors disappeared. If you are able to, I suggest you do the same.
This was on a Windows 7 box.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this problem was caused by my local.properties file showing a different path to the Android SDK. I do development on both Mac OS X and Windows and the properties file was showing my Mac OS X SDK path. Turns out, this file shouldnt even be checked into source control. Ooops!

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found is to check-out some empty project, then import it rather than use the "New project" utility.

Answer (score 1):

The fix for me was on the Known Issues page here: http://tools.android.com/knownissues

I changed

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
```

to:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
```

Reopened Android Studio and voila!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by downloading a fresh copy of AndroidStudio. During one of the updates something went wrong so I delete all config files and freshly downloaded the file from the Internet and then it worked fine for me.

(I'm on a Mac)

Answer (score 0):

If you are still receiving this error when creating a new project, then try opening the project (after error) and removing the following from your build.gradle file in your module.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by installing some extras from Android SDK what I did not think I needed: Google Repository and Google Play services. In addition of Android Support Repository.

When manually running gradle you get more meaningful error messages.