# Failed to import new Gradle project: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject'

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio

when i started android studio  i get this error:

```
Failed to import new Gradle project: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using    Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at     http://gradle.org/docs/1.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read below process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.


Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

i use latest android studio and latest(1.6) gradle. whats the problem here? i use 32bit window 8

Comment: This might also be the case
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609666/could-not-fetch-model-of-type-ideaproject-using-gradle-installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMPORTANT: I done it on fresh android studio!!
if you have plugins and such it may not work for you !

I found the solution that worked for me :

1. Go to [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/downloads)
2. Download last version
3. Open grandle location within Android Studio (in my case is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\plugins\gradle"
4. **Important**: backup your existing Android Studio gradle lib folder (in case things go wrong, as some of the commenters have pointed out)
5. Open download file from 2.
6. Override lib folder within Android Studio with lib folder within downloaded file.

Everything should work like a charm :)

Comment: did the exact same and did not help at all

Comment: this worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609666/could-not-fetch-model-of-type-ideaproject-using-gradle-installation

Comment: This actually disabled my gradle plugin completely. Needed to revert the lib folder.

Comment: Also just disabled plugins

Comment: nope.. this thing blew up my android studio.. continuing the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476219/could-not-fetch-model-of-type-ideaproject-using-gradle-distribution)

Comment: Didn't do anything at all for me, I already was using Gradle 1.6, so the "new" files didn't change anything.

Comment: Don't do this! refer to Ro Owen's answer

Comment: Can you mention the source of your information?

Comment: Had to reinstall android studio, dont do this

Answer (score 42):

If you upgrade your Studio to 0.2 version, then to fix this, open the SDK manager, and make sure that the "Extras/Android Support Repository" (not just Android Support Library) is installed.

Source: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio020released

Comment: this should be the accepted answer as of July 11th 2013

Comment: I tried this does not work. I updated the "Android Support Repository" from Android SDK manager and created a new project but problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a proxy issue, can be solved by adding proxy address.

Studio-->Settings-->HTTP Proxy-->Use Proxy and add proxy details and verify with check connection.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to install the SDK repository as mentioned [in the install notes](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#Installing) at the very bottom of the page. This happens after upgrading from android studio 0.1 to 0.2 when creating new projects or implementing existing ones.

1. Open Android SDK Manager
2. Install Android SDK Repository from the Extra's tab

Answer (score 1):

I made sure I had the latest version of Gradle, but that made no improvement. Then I ran Android Studio using an admin account, at which point all the errors disappeared. If you are able to, I suggest you do the same. This was on a Windows 7 box.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on a Mac:

After updating to Version 0.2.0 I had the problem and here is what I did to fix it:

First I removed all old config/settings files:

```
$ cd
$ find Library/Application\ S* Library/Preference* -iname "*androidstudio*" -exec rm -rf {} +
$ rm -rf .gradle .android
```

And after this didn't help either I freshly downloaded AndroidStudio. And then it worked.
So you might start with a fresh download before removing everything.