# Android Studio missing src and other part of my project after reopening

Tags: android, android-studio

currently I'm exploring on using the Android Studio. It's been a while since I last developed on Android and this is really exciting for me having a new tool to develop in Android. Now I already setup the Android Studio successfully and already tested to create a new sample project last week but today after I opened it a message appears saying that "the folders below are removed from gradle..." it has a checkbox and I don't know why it's checked by default. Since I'm not yet that familiar with the environment I pressed ok then all the src and other folders are now missing. Although I can still access the src folder as well as the classes I created through the use of the navigator on the top part but I can't run the app and it acts really strange compared from before.

Also when I try to create a new project a message appers saying:

"Failed to import new Gradle project: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
Unable to start the daemon process."

Not sure on what to do about this one. Well I know this is still in beta and bugs happen but I hope there's already a workaround for this.

Anyway, here's a screenshot on what happens to my project:
[image]

Comment: Are you able to build from the command line with `./gradle assemble`?

Comment: I got it already. Anyway, I haven't tried that before and I don't even know what it does. Where and when should I use that? Please enlighten me. :)

Comment: So the beauty of this new build system is that under the covers it's just calling gradle tasks. So you should be able to run the `gradlew.bat tasks` from the command prompt. Sorry forgot you were on windows when I wrote the previous comment. The tasks command will show you everything that is available. I highly recommend this video that was just posted: [New Build System](http://youtu.be/LCJAgPkpmR0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried searching answers based on the error message I got from creating a new project and found out about this one:

[Failed to import new Gradle project: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659381/failed-to-import-new-gradle-project-could-not-fetch-model-of-type-ideaproject)

works like charm indeed.