# Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle distribution

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639227/766570) tutorial of embedding an external project in android studio with gradle.. and I got stuck at this error:

> Gradle 'HelloWorldProject' project refresh failed:
>              Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle distribution
>   'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
>              A problem occurred configuring project ':HelloWorld'.
>              A problem occurred configuring project ':HelloWorld'.
>              Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>              Configuration with name 'default' not found.

I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16662045/766570) verbatim, but then I get this error:

[image]

my gradle version: 
`gradle -v`

> Gradle 1.6
>
> Gradle build time: Tuesday, May 7, 2013 9:12:14 AM UTC Groovy: 1.8.6
>   Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012 Ivy: 2.2.0
>   JVM: 1.6.0_45 (Apple Inc. 20.45-b01-451) OS: Mac OS X 10.8.3 x86_64

any ideas?

Comment: I guess you did, but have you checked this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17612960/1658749) ? Hope it helps you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this issue, open the SDK manager, and make sure that the

**Extras/Android Support Repository**

(not just Android Support Library) is installed, and always take a look on [Recent Changes on tool.android.com](http://tools.android.com/recent) after updating Android Studio to newer version.

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0):

use new project/ new module instead of import project/ import module

Comment: while importing project use create project from existing sources

Comment: I don't think this is related to import, it happens too for new projects. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659381/failed-to-import-new-gradle-project-could-not-fetch-model-of-type-ideaproject