# Problems found loading Plugins in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

After updating Gradle as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16662045/932307) the following error appears while using Android Studio 0.2.0

[image]

How to get over this one?

Comment: @GauravAgarwal you can select answer if it helped you

Comment: @AndrewS I am not working on Android Studiio for sometime now therefore I am unable to check any of the suggested solution therefore I am unable to select the correct answer. I am sorry.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal my answer is most rated and it is correct :) was my trouble too and found a fix.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

go to `Settings-Plugins-IDE Settings` and just disable and enable again needed plugins - it helped me.
I think it was some bug on Studio

Comment: how could you find that ? , yes , your solution help me , that is some bug in Stuido . save my time man . :)

Comment: Had the problem in 2.2.2.  Even uninstalling and reinstalling did not help (OSX).

But this worked.

Comment: seriously... I got scared when i see these much of errors. Thank you man, you saved me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Interesting, that this error still stands and this solution still works for AS 3.0.1, after two years.

Comment: I'm on 3.1.2 and I'm surprised this error still exists. Fortunately this solution still holds

Comment: This answer saved me so much time and frustration. Still working on 3.1.3.

Comment: @YogeshLakhotia Yep, it still does. I don't know if anybody can relate. I attempted to close an emulator window and my screen went completely blank. I could not even bring the control panel to show by CTRL+ALT+DEL so I force rebooted the machine. Next time I tried to start the project I was working on this happened. Unchecked the red ones, restarted, checked them again and voilá, it worked as before. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 28):

I have the same error, and I solve it as mentioned above:

1. go as flow `file-->settings-->plugins`
2. then uncheck the red options
3. apply settings You will get error message no problem
4. recheck the unchecked options
5. press ok
6. it will request to restart android studio press ok button and it will solve the error and work fine again

Answer (score 8):

1.Go to settings -> uncheck all red check one's -> apply

2.It will restart your android studio -> OK

3.Go to settings -> Plugins -> check the unchecked one's->apply

4.Restart and update them all.

//done

//thankyou

Comment: It help me for android studio 3.1.3

Answer (score 4):

I try  to remove and  reinstall  Extras or disable and enable plugins but  the problem  is not solved.

I find a solution to correct  that is to  reset **Android Studio** You  have to remove  this  directory and restart **Android Studio** to detect the SDK location:

```
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
```

Answer (score 3):

As you see, image uploaded by you, `Configure`, go to that menu. Now click on `Settings`. Try to find `Plugins` in `IDE Settings`. Here look out for `Gradle` and check whether it is installed or not.

If not, Click on `Install JetBrains Plugin...` or `Browse Categories` and find `Gradle`. Now on top, besides `Refresh` button there is a `Download and Install` button. Using that button install `Gradle` Plugin.

Answer (score 2):

> Andorid studio -> preferences > plugins, enable "support" plugin. And then if there are red plugin, disabled it and restart android studio

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->Settings-> Plugins then uncheck then check all the red highlighted plugin then restart the android studio if require

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way..
Go to file then settings (Ctrl+alt+S) > then go to plugins > on the "show" dropdown button select disabled > unchecke the check-buttons then they'll disappear> again select disabled then check them and press OK. On request to restart android studio, restart it and it'll be working fine

Answer (score 0):

For Mac, this worked

1. Menu > Preferences > Plugins
2. Uncheck all
3. Android studio will ask to restart, restart it
4. Check all again
5. Restart Again
6. And Voila!

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking the gradle plugin and checking it again then restarting android studio and selecting the SDK location and downloading the missing dependencies worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with reset android studio settings.

**On Windows:**

Go to your User Folder - on Windows 7/8 this would be:

> [SYSDRIVE]:\Users[your username] (ex. C:\Users\JohnDoe)

In this folder there should be a folder called **.AndroidStudioBeta** or **.AndroidStudio** (notice the period at the start - so on some OSes it would be hidden).

**Delete** this folder (or better yet, move it to a backup location - so you can return it if something goes wrong).

This should reset your Android Studio settings to default.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19397632/793880

Answer (score 0):

2020/12/10 - Ubuntu 18.04 and Android Studio 4.2
I solved it this way:
Using strace I've found the user installed plugins directory on "/home//.local/share/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.2" (not documented in any place i've read, nor official doc, nor IntelijIdea either)
Just deleted the directories of the failing plugins (that are not listed with installed plugins, so can't uncheck anything), and problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'Item'.
Text(Item.items[index].price.toString()+" S.p", style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white)),

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).