# How to reset Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to reset `Android Studio 0.2.13` to the default state. That means reset all settings, remove all projects, all gradle files so that it would act like a fresh installation. What steps do I have to follow to achieve this?

Comment: It sounds like you really just want to uninstall and reinstall it.

Comment: @Tanis.7x Expensive bandwidth.. :(

Answer (score 170, accepted):

I only know how to do this on Windows (but it should be similar on any OS, you will just need to find the correct location yourself - google search would help with that).

**On Windows:**

Go to your **User Folder** - on Windows 7/8 this would be:

`[SYSDRIVE]:\Users\[your username]` (ex. `C:\Users\JohnDoe\`)

In this folder there should be a folder called `.AndroidStudioBeta` or `.AndroidStudio` (notice the period at the start - so on some OSes it would be hidden).

**Update**

Now, Android Studio settings is at:

`C:\Users\<Your User>\AppData\Roaming\Google\.AndroidStudio4.X`

Delete this folder (or better yet, move it to a backup location - so you can return it if something goes wrong).

This should reset your Android Studio settings to default.

Comment: Even though I've done this, it still shows the same projects in the recent projects. I want to reset it since it has issues importing from Github (fails in a split of a second, without showing any warning).

Comment: @androiddeveloper have you tried clearing recent files from within windows? On windows 7/8, while the app is running (or if it is pinned to the taskbar) simply right click (or click and drag up) the icon on the taskbar to see the list of recent projects. Now right click the item you want to remove and select `Remove from list` (repeat for all items to remove).

Comment: @free3dom Never mind. I've forgot to install Git. Now it works fine. Not sure though what I did in order to remove the recently opened projects. Thank you for trying to help me. Here, get a +1 .

Comment: in windows i just removed the ".AndroidStudio2.2\config\port.lock" file, no need to reset if some one facing crash in studio or unable load the recent projects

Comment: Any alternative to reset the UI and toolbars, without deleting the folder and plugins and repositories will also take off from this deletion?

Answer (score 135):

**On Mac OS X**

Remove these directories:

```
~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudioBeta  
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudioBeta  
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioBeta
```

Comment: this answer solved my problem that android studio can not recognize type String.

Comment: As of 0.8 release, replace `AndroidStudioPreview` with `AndroidStudioBeta`

Comment: I can confirm this works for version 1.1.0. just replace `AndroidStudioPreview` for `AndroidStudio`

Comment: Or just use an app like AppCleaner and select everything except of AndroidStudio.app. It just removed about 4 GB from old Android Studio configs on my machine.

Comment: Also: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio*`

Answer (score 61):

For MaxOSX:

```
rm -rfv ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*
rm -rfv ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
rm -rfv ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
rm -rfv ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
rm -rfv ~/.AndroidStudio*
```

For Android Studio 1.2.2 version, config path is `~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio1.2/` and `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio1.2`, so it's better to `rm` matching prefix.

Comment: @cesarferreira For android 1.1, directory names are `AndroidStudio` without version name. Add * to cover all cases.

Comment: worked for me `Mac OS Catalina 10.15.5 ` `Android Studio 4.0.1`

Answer (score 52):

You can reset it via menu:
`File > Manage IDE Settings > Restore Default Settings`

[image]

Comment: Best and simplest option out of my view

Comment: Straight to the point. Well done 

Answer (score 35):

On Mac OS X with Android Studio >= 1.0.0

Run these lines:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio 
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio
```

Answer (score 29):

close project if not done earlier or working on a new project. Now open android studio and click on the configure settings button available at the bottom of the small window of android studio, there you will see restore settings to default option. The safe way to do it.

[image: configure settings -> restore settings to default]

Answer (score 16):

From Linux this is what I did:

Remove the .AndroidStudioBeta folder:

```
rm -r ~/.AndroidStudioBeta
```

Remove the project folder. For example:

```
rm -r ~/AndroidStudioProjects
```

I needed to do both or stuff kept hanging around.

Hope this helps.

Comment: *DON'T RUN THE SECOND COMMAND WITHOUT BACKING UP YOUR PROJECT.... UNLESS ALL YOUR PROJECT WILL BE GONE BEWARE*

Answer (score 12):

**Linux**

Android Studio 4.2:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio*
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio*
rm -rf ~/.cache/Google/AndroidStudio*
```

Android Studio 1.0.0:

`rm -R ~/.AndroidStudio/config/`

Android Studio 0.8.6:

`rm -R ~/.AndroidStudioBeta/config/`

Answer (score 12):

On a Mac

Delete these using the terminal (usage: rm -rf folderpath):

```
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudioBeta
```

Answer (score 7):

On MAC delete this folder:

~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

Comment: This answer worked for me on 4.2, except, of course, that the name of the folder ended in 4.2 instead of 4.1

Answer (score 4):

We can no longer reset android studio to it's default state by the answers/methods given in this question from android studio 3.2.0
Here is the updated new method to do it (It consumes less time as it does not require any update/installation).

For Windows/Mac

1. Open my computer
2. Go to  `C:\Users\Username\.android\build-cache`
3. Delete the cache/files found inside the folder `build-cache`
4. Note: do not delete the folder named as "3.2.0" and "3.2.1" which will be inside the `build-cache`
5. Restart Android studio.

and that would completely reset your android studio settings from Android studio 3.2.0 and up.

Comment: This solution fixed my issues on a mac for me ~/username/.android/build-cache

Comment: Working solution for Android Studio version 3.3.0

Answer (score 4):

**for ( Android Studio Version >= 3.0.0 & macOS)**

> mine( Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1 & macOS 12.6)

To reset Android Studio back to its default:

[image]

1. Open Android Studio and click on "File," located in the lower left-hand corner of your screen.
2. From the list of settings that appears, locate the option for "Restore Default Settings."

Resetting Android Studio to its default settings removes any changes and caches you have made to your settings and allows you to start fresh as if Android Studio was a brand-new installation.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Home
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (to show hidden files)
3. Delete AndroidStudio setting folder (like image below)
4. Restart Android Studio

[image: Android Studio setting folders highlighted]

Comment: Not valid for Android Studio 3.6.3 and above

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows and Android Studio 4 and above, the location to the directory is C:\Users(your name)\AppData\Roaming\Google\

Simple delete the Google folder to reset all settings. Open Android Studio and do not import settings when asked

Answer (score 2):

Open Android Studio > Configure > Restore default settings ...
[image: img example]

Answer (score 1):

Build - Clean project.
Basically, this is a problem with studio 3.0. 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0.html (authorized link).

Answer (score 1):

Windows Users: 
Look for C:->Users->YourUserName->.AndroidStudio or .AndroidStudioBeta folder. Delete that.

Mac Users: 
Delete these using the terminal (usage: rm -rf folderpath): 
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudioBeta

Linus Users: 
Delete these using the terminal (usage: rm -r folderpath):
~/.AndroidStudioBeta/config or
~/.AndroidStudio/config

Answer (score 0):

Linux AnddroidStudio 1.1.0

```
rm -r ~/.AndroidStudio
```

Comment: It may also be located under `~/.config/Google/`