# How to always keep Android Studio Tool Windows in Un Docked Mode

Tags: android, macos, user-interface, intellij-idea, android-studio

I recently switched to Android Studio and noticed that the tool windows have a Docked Mode option when I click on the little Gear icon in each tool window.

[image]

I personally prefer the Un-Docked Mode(as the tool window minimizes conveniently when I click in the editor) and set every tool window(except the Project Explorer) to be Un-Docked.

But every time I restart Android Studio it **irritatingly** converts all Tool Windows back to Docked Mode.This was very easy to do in Eclipse but after searching online for quite a bit, I still don't know how to save the UnDocked mode for Tool Windows in Android Studio. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: My settings are saved when I do this, so it could be that there is some problem with your config. However, you may want to try and use `Window` -> `Store Current Layout as Default` from the main menu and see if that does the trick. If that fails, maybe try to reset your configuration (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384033/how-to-reset-android-studio)).

Comment: I updated to Android Studio 0.5.5 and the problem was fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today's update to Android Studio 0.5.5 fixed the problem for me! Now Android Studio always remembers to save the state of the tool windows!

Answer (score 1):

Unlike @kpsfoo, I want the tool window on the docked mode, but I did something and wasn't able to go back... Finally I went to file > settings > I did search for "docked" in the search box and created a keyboard shortcut. This way I'm able to quickly switch on and off the docked mode.

I hope it could help somebody...