# Can you create a new project while one is open? / Is it possible to duplicate projects?

Tags: android-studio, osx-mavericks

I seem to only be able to create a new project from the "Quick Start" panel.  And this screen is only available when you don't have any projects open.

I know I can close all projects, create a new one, then select File >> open recent if I want multiple projects up.  But is it possible to create a new project, say from the File menu while I am already in another project?  The only option for creation there is for new files for the current project.

Is it possible to copy/duplicate a project without having to copy/paste the file folders and then import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Android Studio on Windows, so I'm not sure whether it's any different on OSX, but the `File` menu does allow for creation of new projects.

The screenshot below shows the `File` menu while a project is open. Note the highlighted item. If this is missing for you then you may have some problem with your installation - or the OSX version is seriously different, but I doubt that.

You could try resetting your installation to default (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384033/how-to-reset-android-studio) for instructions). Just be sure to backup the config files (instead of deleting them) in case this does not solve your problem.

[image: Android Studio File Menu]

The only other thing might be different on my system is that I do not use Gradle projects, but I don't really see how that would change this behaviour - but that might be the case.

Comment: thanks free3dom.  A lot of things were messy in the install.  Reinstalling did the trick.  And what about the question regarding duplicating a project? Any idea?

Comment: Not problem. The way I duplicate a project is to just copy the folder to a new location and opening it (not importing) - don't know of any other way.

Comment: Gotcha. So copy the folder to a new location in the file directory, then in AS File >> Open the project?  I had tried something similar but every time I ran either the original project or the duplicated one in the emulator, it would replace the other one.  Something in the project is identifying it as the same project. DO you know what that might be?

Comment: Yeah, once you've copied the project to a new location it will be an exact duplicate. In order to differentiate them you need to rename the **package** (which uniquely identifies your app). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package) for various ways to do that :)

Comment: sorry I didn't give the details, but I did rename it.  And it still continued replacing it. I'll check out the link you gave.