# Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT:

Tags: android, gradle

Android Studio is not running any my projects, even a hello world app.

I have tried almost everything.
I have been banging my head for 2 days now. I tried all these:

[How do I solve the INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153515/how-do-i-solve-the-install-failed-dexopt-error)

I have disabled instant run with no effect. 
I have cleaned my project with no effect. 
I have tried building on it a real phone with the same error.
I have tried wiping out data of the emulator with no effect.
After trying almost everything here.
I also uninstalled Android Studio and reinstalled it three times and no effect.

gradle: app
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tete.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

The project level gradle file is:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

It is a very simple Hello world project. 
Please tell me what more information you need. 
This issue has started making me angry.

Comment: Do one thing go to File-->Invalidate cache/Restart after that  clean build project. if now work then kindly paste the code of Project level gradle.

Comment: @HemantParmar tried that, didn't helped.

Comment: @Rishabh   check this link   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568621/failure-to-install-apk-install-failed-dexopt-android-studio

Comment: @MurugananthamS I have tried that, as mentioned I have rebuilt the project, I have created new projects multiple times but with no effect

Comment: By the way, I use Ubuntu, if that is required.