# Android Studio 0.9.2 to 0.9.3 error: toString() method cannot be referenced

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just updated android studio release from 0.9.2 to 0.9.3 and opening an existing project (that was running with 0.9.2) the following error (red underline) appears in all '.toString' methods (f.i. Integer.toString): non static method toString() cannot be referenced from a static context. But the debug does not show anything and the app runs properly. Please any suggestion?

example:

```
private String read(String nomefile)
{
    String dati=null;
    try{
        FileInputStream fin=openFileInput(nomefile);
        int c;
        String temp="";
        while ((c=fin.read())!=-1)
        {
            temp=temp+Character.toString(((char)c));
        }
        dati=temp;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dati;
}
```

and '.toString' is red underlined with this annotation: 'non static method toString() cannot be referenced from a static context'
Upate:
replacing “Character.toString(...)” with “Character.valueOf(...)” seems all ok (no red underline). This means that toString method will be deprecated?

Comment: copy & paste your LogCat into a code block

Comment: Logcat won't help here. It's an IDE issue.

Comment: Are you sure that everything in your SDK manager is up to date? I've had problems with AS and the SDK manager not being up to date. When I update AS, I always go in and update the SDK manager,

Comment: Only android 5.0 (API 21) is not installed

Comment: Post the error details from the Android Studio Event Log window and an example line on which it says there is an error.

Comment: That's weird. `Character.toString()` should be fine. You can try resetting Android Studio completely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384033/how-to-reset-android-studio

Comment: Vote on the issue in the android tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79420

Comment: Is your activity static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common bug.
The fix is going to be delivered at 0.9.4 according this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79420

Answer (score 2):

Try going to File > Invalidate Caches & Restart. I just upgraded and do not have this problem.

**edit**

It appears this is a [known issue with 0.9.3](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79420#c31). A permanent fix should be available in the next Canary release.