# Android Studio 1.0 build too slow

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I've updated Android Studio to 1.0 RC (both 1 and 2) from 0.9x and my project build time passed from 20 sec to around 90 sec.

Anyone is having the same problem?

**UPDATE**

Running the same task on terminal, I see that the "Resolving dependencies" step is taking most of the extra time.

**UPDATE 2**

Thanks to @bond, I've noticed that going offline lowers the build time to about 30 sec, so I tried to use mavenLocal() on the build.gradle, but no luck there either.

Top Level build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: "and my project build time passed from 20 sec to around 90 sec" -- what were you using to build for the "20 sec" scenario? In other words, what are we comparing AS 1.0RC to? An earlier version of Android Studio? Eclipse? Command-line Gradle for Android? Ant? IntelliJ IDEA? NetBeans? Something else?

Comment: Do you have Make Project Automatically under the Preferences -> Compiler (Gradle) tab?

Comment: you probably need better CPU and more RAM, I have 8 GB RAM at work in my dev machine otherwise it'd be an atrocity (hence why I used ADT instead in the past)

Comment: Might be some configuration issue. Have you tried [resetting Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384033/how-to-reset-android-studio)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I ended up building the first time online, and after that switching to offline mode

[image: Gradle Options]

That lowered the time to ~14 secs.

My guess is that gradle is trying to resolve dependencies online ignoring my "mavenLocal()" (and all its variants)

Answer (score 32):

In compiler settings (Android Studio -> Preferences -> Project settings[*your project*] -> Compiler (Gradle-based Android Projects)), type --offline in the "Command-line options" box.

from ~4 minutes to ~20 seconds.

Comment: Thanks! From ~8 minutes to ~40 seconds (behind corporate firewall)

Comment: Thanks, from 4 minutes to ~15-20 seconds here too!

Comment: 1 minute to 10 seconds.  Amazing!

Comment: Thanks! Why is this not the accepted answer???? I was averaging upwards of 5 minutes for a Rebuild and I'm now down to 1min 27sec.

Comment: Type "--offline" in "Command-line options" box, if some confution.

Comment: Use this one little trick to reduce compile times from over 4 minutes to less than 20 seconds! SSDs hate him!

Comment: You are a lifesaver.  This is huge!

Answer (score 1):

For **Newcomers**, who can't find Gradle Offline settings (Android studio 1.5.1)

File -> Settings -> Build,execution, deployment -> Build tools -> Gradle
last checkbox (Offline work)

and thanks a lot guys - from like 10 mins to 30sec

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up your Android Studio performance and build time, you just follow these:

- Use/open single project at a time
- clean your project after running your app in emulator every time
- use mobile/external device instead of emulator
- don't close emulator after using once, use same emulator for running app each time

Comment: I already do all of those, also, my dev behaviour didn't change from AS 0.9x to 1.x

Comment: Tell me your system configuration

Comment: Actually a hardware-accelerated emulator could be way faster than a normal mobile device. Also could upload large APK faster than the slow USB of the device. But running emulator on machine with just 4GB RAM could lead to lots of swapping and degrage performance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind corporate firewall? You might want to try the following:
1. Go to Settings> Compiler(Gradle-Based Android Projects)
2. Command-line Options: put "--stacktrace --debug"
3. Build your project
4. Look at "Gradle Console" (Bottom right side of AS)

This might tell you where it is stuck.
Note: Gradle goes to repositories in order it is defined in build.gradle, make sure you have correct order (go to internal first, and fall back to other etc.)

Comment: ok, you did point me in the right direction, but no solution found yet... Going offline lowers the build time to ~20 sec... but calling mavenLocal() first on the build script does not make any difference. See update 2 above

Comment: @Cheborra, did you see anything on the gradle console after                         you turned on the stacktrace and debug options? (Can you post your repositories section and dependencies section from ur build gradle file?)

Comment: Nothing worth mentioning

Comment: Try this one>> maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

Comment: Another thing to note is what do you have on ur build.gradle on the top level one (not in ur module but the level up).

Comment: The one published is the top-level one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68086/discussion-between-bond-and-cheborra).

Comment: can you post one in the module too? how many modules do you have? (app, wear, tv?)

Comment: only one module, 4 buildTypes and 2 Flavors tough... lets continue on chat

Answer (score 0):

Create a `gradle.properties` file in the following directory:

- home//.gradle/ (Linux)
- /Users//.gradle/ (Mac)
- C:\Users\.gradle (Windows)

And add this line to the file:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```