# Close white cursor in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, text-cursor

[image: AndroidStudio]

In Android Studio, my cursor is white rectangle. I'm cannot write anything. And changed my keyboard button actions.

h-->left arrow j-->down arrow k--> up arrow l-->right arrow

How can I fix problem or can I reset Android Studio settings?

Comment: Press insert button once.

Comment: Dont work insert button

Comment: At the bottom of editor, there are 3 columns containing some text. What is the content of middle column? `Smart Insert` or `Overwrite`?

Comment: How can i reset to default settings

Comment: I reseted settings and fixed problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384033/how-to-reset-android-studio

Comment: Same problem here but in the terminal, I'm using Git bash (any_path\Git\bin\sh.exe).. none of the solutions works! :((

Comment: if you are using ideaVim plugin. Simply disable it.

Comment: For people voting to close: Questions about IDEs are not "General computing hardware and software."  Please read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), which will tell you that questions that "directly involve tools used primarily for programming" are on-topic here.

Answer (score 29):

Just got the same problem as yours. And this is the solution:

Go to `File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance`, then uncheck the `Use block caret`

[image]

Comment: I reseted settings and fixed problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384033/how-to-reset-android-studio in Feb 19 at 13:00

Answer (score 25):

Try `fn + ins`. That worked for me.

Comment: That worked for me as well, i was just trying to figure whats is the shortcut, thanks

Comment: What is `ins` in macOS?

Comment: there is no ```ins``` button on mac

Answer (score 19):

Go to settings and plugins and just disable the IdeaVim plugin it works in 2020.itx also occurs due to this extension.

Answer (score 13):

In windows, <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>insert</kbd> worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

go to plugins and disable IdeaVim then restart android studio it will be ok ...

Answer (score 4):

Presse <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>. It will work instantly.

Answer (score 2):

Press Fn + Del on your keyboard together.
Explanation: Its because Delete key on keyboard has Insert function. So pressing Del along with Fn key will enable Insert mode within your editor from Overwrite mode as in your case.

Answer (score 1):

It's `ins` in the latest version of Android Studio.

Comment: This answer was already provided. And the question has been resolved in the meantime (last comment).

Answer (score 1):

In windows if you press INSERT key cursor mode will get change,use WINDOWS + INSERT to get back into normal mode

Answer (score 1):

For mac users just right click and deselect "Column selection mode" or press Shift + Command + 8

Answer (score 0):

Just restart Android Studio and voilà !

None of the other solutions worked for me (Windows 7, maybe with an inactive Lock Num key).

Comment: No need to restart Android Studio for this, `fn` + `ins` doing the work.

Answer (score 0):

in MacOS

-> **Uncheck**  `[Use block caret]`

[image]