# Android studio white cursor not letting me to type

Tags: android-studio, flutter, intellij-idea

I have gone through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606348/close-white-cursor-in-android-studio) and tried all the solutions but none of them worked.

Screenshot:

[image]

It started after I installed [Flutter Pub Version Checker](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12400-flutter-pub-version-checker) plugin, and I remember Android Studio popped up a dialog asking something like, (I don't remember all the details)

> Do you want to allow multiple entries on holding a button X, you can always run xyz command to get back...

I agreed to that block and then I started having this issue. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to uninstall this plugin to get the IDE back to normal. I just created a new [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-2018)