# Android Studio won't open any projects

Tags: android, android-studio

the past day I did unistalled Android Studio because after I did close a project it prompted me something like "Do you want to unlink/delete the 'app'" or something similar, of course, I said YES, and after that when I tried to open back any project of mine it first says it doesn't have the SDK 22 installed, after installed it just opens a new Android Studio windows but.. blank as the previous one, even if I rebuild the project it does the same thing: it keeps itself blank.

I do not know what to do, I did reinstalled it like 4 times so far!

Comment: Have you tried resetting the Android Studio? may be that should do the trick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384033/how-to-reset-android-studio

Comment: Look @dhaval , this trick helped me out making new projects, so now everything would work just fine, but when I open my old projects it just doesn't open 'em, It says that as my old path for the SDK isn't available , it will use the new one (that's fair by the way) but after this pop up it tries to load it but it doesn't, there's just the name of the project and stop

Comment: so your Studio is pointing to correct SDK folder path but some of the projects are pointing to different (unavailable) SDK path right?

Comment: If it is screwing up inside the Studio, you can close the project, go to folder where the project is stored and update the SDK path in `local.properties` file and reopen the project

Comment: Thanks! I'll try right now

Comment: Mmmm strange, the path seems to be the correct one.. @dhaval

Comment: Don't really what to do now

Comment: And did you check your gradle files including settings.gradle?

Comment: What should I look for in it?

Comment: Just that `build.gradle` files exist and `settings.gradle` file includes all the available modules. Usually if there is something wrong with gradle files then Studio throws gradle specific error, but as it is not happening in your case. I would simply open the new project which is working and the old one which is not working on file system and just check the non-source files

Comment: I'll let you know thanks

Comment: There was not a folder, added it but noway, it won't load! May I contact you in someway, and then post back the answer?

Comment: @dhaval What you think?

Comment: Sorry was away from desk, you can get my email from my profile page (which is allowed as per meta exchange rules)

Comment: Done, thanks for your time @dhaval

Comment: Don't worry about that @dhaval ! By the way I've sent the needed items to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was **NOT** an Android Studio issue..
I just had to open the project's files as they won't show if you open a new project already started. ***So you have to select them from the menu on the left-side and.. that's it!***

Yeah.. embarassing how simple it is! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the projects on a different device..
 if you are shure its not the projects fault...
 uninstall AS and look for possible registry entries that might be left...

Comment: How to look for possible registry entries left? @Minzkraut

Comment: there are many registry cleaner tools in the web... you can also look for them yourself if youre careful.
On windows hit "win + r" and type "regedit" if you didn't know that yet.
You can find some information on where these keys (program keys)  are stored most commonly on google...

Comment: Mmmm don't wanna touch the reg right now, by the way I'll later if we don't understand the issue after that pop up I explained in the upper comment :)