# Reset default gradle and plugin for android studio to be up to date when creating new projects?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Is there a way to reset the default  gradle and plugin, without resetting all my settings, so I don't keep having these errors when creating new projects?

> Error: Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to

[image]

[image]

So in the top level build.gradle I update to:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'

}
```

[image]

[image]

And then change the gradle to 2.10 as per requirements [here.](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)

> 2.0.0-alpha5 (2016/1/14)  // hence alpha6
>   Needs gradle 2.10 to work

[image]

Comment: what's version of Android Studio do yoy use?

Comment: find `.android` and `idea` folders (on linux are hidden in home directory, just Ctrl+h to unhide) and delete them,. Then open Android Studio - I've already done it and it would dwelete of all exisitng settings

Comment: no you should have one config `.idea` in your home ditrctory. 5GB? Hmm check what is inside, it seems to be that you have already installed some emulators. Don't be scared - it would reset your IDE, alike you have had already installed so you would see welcome views like asking which them do you prefer

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384033/how-to-reset-android-studio

Comment: @MsYvette have you try to remove old files from `.gradle` folder? I'd delete all rubbish from there first. From `wrapper` folder, `caches` and, probably, also `daemon`?   (For me - MacOS - it's a hidden folder \users\<my user>\.gradle . I suspect, in Windows it should be in similar location). Let me know, if it helps

Comment: Oops. Was it because of deleting these files??? I'm terrible sorry :-)

Comment: but when i did this my new created project was with this setting only

Comment: wait a sec let me check what i did exactly

Comment: i changed this into settings and never that issue again , dont know if it work for me by chance or not for you

Comment: first i changed in project structure and then changed setting to default gradle wrapper then this issue disappear and never came again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102336/discussion-between-ankitagrawal-and-ms-yvette).

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to follow below step to use **Default gradle wrapper(recommended)**:

Android studio -> Settings -> build tools -> gradle -> Project-level settings -> select Use default gradle wrapper(recommended).

And sync gradle and rebuild your project.

See Below image to get more idea:

[image]

It's work for me. I hope its helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio Template Files located on below path:

**{android_studio_installation_path}\plugins\android\lib\templates\**

Now for editing every type of Android Studio Template Project you must edit respective file

For Example: (edit android studio new project template)
we must edit below files:

**{above_path}\gradle-projects\NewAndroidModule\root\build.gradle.ftl**

In this file you must add dependencies that you want to add in every project that you create it, inside the block of dependencies

```
dependencies {}
```

Hope my description has been helpful