# Change default classpath in android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, classpath, build.gradle

I always get following error whenever I create a new project:

> Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to "ccbf255801ffbc86319e3fd14bdc0682272bf5c9"
>   Fix plugin version and sync project
> Open File

Somebody please help.

I have tried everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984905/reset-default-gradle-and-plugin-for-android-studio-to-be-up-to-date-when-creatin/39100244?noredirect=1#comment65547826_39100244) but is not helping

Comment: could you try to update plugin version inside ${project}/build.gradle, and gradle version inside ${project}/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties?  also check your local.properties for sdk/ndk path is correct [but this error may not related to that].

Comment: @Gerry please check my comment on fdsilva answer. I don't want to edit it for every project I create. I want to do it for whole system.

Comment: true, I understand now that you do not want to update that often.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2') {
          force = true
}
```

It works for me,
I hope it's help's you

Comment: But I would have to do this in every project I create, right? I want every project to get initialized with 2.1.0 build tools but they get initialized with 2.2.0-alpha6

Comment: Unfortunately yes, you have to do it for every project, which version is your Android studio and you're gradle?

Comment: My studio is 2.2 Preview 6. In File->Project Structure->Project pane **Gradle Version**:2.10 and **Android Plugin Version**:2.1.0

Comment: @RushiMThakker, unfortunately, you have to do do it for all your project's, if has some way to do this for all projects, I didn't figure it out yet. I hope it helps you

Comment: Oh!! I wish it could be possible :(