# Android Studio 3.0 set path to project

Tags: android, android-studio

My little brother some how changed the path setting in Android Studio 3.0 today.
Every time I try to reset the path from the configure screen AS tells me that the file exists. The old path is C:\androidBook. When I try to create a new project it gives the project the name "androidBook" I am also not sure if he deleted the gradle settings in this folder. Old projects still open but I need to know how to reset the path so I can create new projects. Also I am seeing gradle folders in the androidBook folder So my desperate question is how to reset the path?
Do I also need to delete the gradle folders that were created I do not think they should be in this folder

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34984905/7427111

Comment: @DhavalJardosh I do not have this path Android studio -> Settings -> build tools -> gradle -> Project-level settings -> select Use default gradle wrapper(recommended).

Comment: Mac or Windows?

Comment: @DhavalJardosh Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: File->Setting->Build,Deployment and ... -> .... Try something like this...

Comment: @DhavalJardosh No it is Settings Build Gradle and that is it

Comment: @DhavalJardosh I did discover he tried to import a JavaFX project from NetBeans and that is how the path got changed I have two projects in my Net Beans work folder He also tried to create a project named androdBook which is how the gradle files were created in the androidBook work folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164774/discussion-between-dhaval-jardosh-and-james-duh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@James_Duh Back up all your projects before you do that delete the gradle files that were created in your androidBook folder they do not belong in that folder and it is confusing Android Studio the correct path for projects in your case is this
C:\androidBook\ALayoutTest where androidBook is the work folder and ALayoutTest is the name of the project so when your little brother created the project named 
androidBook that sent everything side ways for Android Studio Also delete the Android Studio projects that are in your Net Beans work folder Before you do that copy and paste the Java and XML files is some folder they you can use Sublime Text to paste the code back into a new project in Android Studio

Comment: That worked great now I know how the gradle files were created in my work folder