# Android Studio large backup directories

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

Using Android Studio (currently 2.1.2) on Windows 10.

There are large folders in the users directory that appear to be backups from older versions, but take up roughly 9 GB of space I'd like back.

> C:\Users\Me\.AndroidStudio
>
> C:\Users\Me\.AndroidStudio1.2
>
> C:\Users\Me\.AndroidStudio1.3
>
> C:\Users\Me\.AndroidStudio1.4
>
> C:\Users\Me\.AndroidStudio1.5
>
> C:\Users\Me\.AndroidStudio2.0
>
> C:\Users\Me\.AndroidStudio2.1
>
> C:\Users\Me\.AndroidStudioPreview
>
> C:\Users\Me\.AndroidStudioPreview1.2

**Is there any reason for me to keep these files?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384033/how-to-reset-android-studio says all your Android Studio settings live in those folders. You might be able to remove folders for old AS versions, but I would definitely not touch the 2.1 folder.

Comment: I removed all but the "AndroidStudio2.1" folder. No ill effects and it reclaimed over 8GB in disk space.