# Move to next/previous tab shortcut on Mac is not working

Tags: macos, phpstorm, keymaps

I'm using PhpStorm v2017.1.3 and I'm having an issue while trying to move to the next/previous tab using the shortcuts `Ctrl + Left/Right`. I can assure that

[image: this is the right shortcut]

I tried to move to another tab using the button "Select next tab" and it seems to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Go to `Preferences | Keymap` -- there is "find by shortcut" button (next to search field) -- see if IDE will recognize/register that shortcut at all. I mean -- it could be an OS-wide shortcut that is handled by MacOS itself.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147394 -- check comments -- especially last one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Launch `System Preferences` and select `Keyboard` > `Shortcuts` > `Mission Control`

<kbd>⌃←</kbd> and <kbd>⌃→</kbd> are predefined to `Move left / right a space` as global shortcuts.

Disable both.

Answer (score -1):

Today I faced the same problem. I am not sure why because the Android version I have is the Artic fox 2020.3.1 and this issue is fixed. Anyway, what I did is I reset android studio.

Ref
[How to reset Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384033/how-to-reset-android-studio)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30840934)