# Stuck on Android Studio Splash Screen(Startup screen)!

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8, ide, android-studio-2.3

I just joined course and downloaded AS from official Website. Install java(JDK). Used JAVAC command in CMD and java worked. then Installed AS Setup but just hang on loading!!!

[image: image description here]

I have correct Env. variable though and has everything perfectly set up.

in furthur i tried disable.android.first.run=true in that matter i got no SDK or Missing SDK MSG :(

and when i put correct path of SDK(AppData) it just stuck on that window and wont let me start new project!!

pls help me :(

Comment: Could be late, just had this problem on mac. Just reset it https://stackoverflow.com/a/19467497/1599611

Answer (score 0):

Could be late, just had this problem on mac. Just reset it https://stackoverflow.com/a/19467497/1599611. Figure out the problem, it was the Material Theme UI plugin when you install the material wallpaper

Answer (score 0):

For me just killed *java* process and again started Android Studio.