# Android studio stuck at splash screen

Tags: android-studio-2.3

when I write the disable.android.first.run=true in idea.properties, then it stuck on welcome screen and nothing happen when  I click on new project.

Comment: answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19467497/1505493

Answer (score 0):

try opening it from terminal like `./studio.sh` and you can see the verbose output of what's going wrong. Maybe something with your path variable?