# Android Studio Canary stuck on splash screen

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

Android Studio canary gets stuck on the splash screen and this has been happening since the last few releases of canary but the stable release works with no such issue. I tried the fixes from this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45011960/android-studio-stuck-at-splash-screen) but it didn't work. I am currently running macOS Mojave 10.14.6. [image: sppash screen]

Answer (score 4):

**On Mac OS**

Remove these directories:

```
~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudioBeta  
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudioBeta  
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioBeta
```

Comment: @Nsnik Glad that's helps you :) please mark this as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: again I am facing the same issue, I removed the above-mentioned directories but still, I am stuck on the splash screen