# Ambiguous method call. Both findViewById (int) in AppCompactActivity and Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I refer this link 
[Error : Ambiguous method call. Both findViewById (int) in AppCompactActivity and Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46900261/error-ambiguous-method-call-both-findviewbyid-int-in-appcompactactivity-and)
to solve but there is no import android.app.Activity and also if I convert my import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity into android.app.Activity then the error goes but I want to use AppCompatActivity.

I also update all libraries in SDK and also invalidate and restart but nothing works.

why this error occurs and how to solve this?

Comment: The import may not be there but are you sure that your Activity is not extending that class explicitly by declaring the full android.app.Activity?

Comment: yes i'm sure there is only this line import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

Comment: I'm talking about where you Class extends <Super Class> are you sure that super class is not explicitly defined?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to latest version of `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: @ JoxTraex, no not extending activity it is like this
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: @Dipali shah, yes i updated all libraries

Comment: Pleas check  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46900261/error-ambiguous-method-call-both-findviewbyid-int-in-appcompactactivity-and/#51129460

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have something like that

```
ViewClass view = (ViewClass)findViewById(R.id.view);
```

in your code and you'd updated API level?
If so, change your code to

```
ViewClass view = findViewById(R.id.view); // without redundant cast
```

The `findViewById` method signature was changed in API 25, please refer to [SDK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int))

Comment: hi @Northern Poet, i just updated 26 sdk tools to 27 and it runs perfectly without removing anything in code

Answer (score 2):

If you recently updated your project to API 26, try doing invalidate caches/restart, then re-sync gradle.

Answer (score 0):

If doing invalidate caches/restart, then re-sync gradle, does not work, restart the computer, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was working with a new project and in gradle files did not have version numbers set in them, there was "N" across minsdkversion and targetsdkversion,
changing to desired sdk version solved the problem