# "Got negative length for block" error on Android Studio while trying to get a signed apk

Tags: java, android, apk, sign

I had it working for months, and some days out of nowere the Studio just could not sign my app anymore. I can build it as release or debug without a sign, so it seems to not be related to the code itself.
Here's what happens: when I go at "Build >> Generate Signed APK" the windows won't show up and the "!" sign will start to blink red. When I click the sign, I get this:

Error:

```
Got negative length for block
```

and Details:

```
Got negative length for block
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Got negative length for block
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.HashedBlockInputStream.load(HashedBlockInputStream.java:129)
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.HashedBlockInputStream.get(HashedBlockInputStream.java:100)
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.HashedBlockInputStream.read(HashedBlockInputStream.java:66)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:238)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:117)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipString(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:518)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:946)
    at com.intellij.util.JdomKt.loadDocument(jdom.kt:78)
    at com.intellij.util.JdomKt.loadElement(jdom.kt:73)
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxKt.load(kdbx.kt:89)
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxKt.access$load(kdbx.kt:1)
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxStreamFormat.load(kdbx.kt:57)
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxKt.loadKdbx(kdbx.kt:36)
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.KeePassCredentialStore.<init>(KeePassCredentialStore.kt:82)
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.KeePassCredentialStore.<init>(KeePassCredentialStore.kt:44)
    at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.impl.PasswordSafeImplKt.computeProvider(PasswordSafeImpl.kt:38)
    at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.impl.PasswordSafeImpl.<init>(PasswordSafeImpl.kt:46)
    at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.impl.PasswordSafeImpl.<init>(PasswordSafeImpl.kt)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:103)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ServiceManagerImpl.java:220)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:239)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:206)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.doGetService(ServiceManager.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:39)
    at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.PasswordSafe.getInstance(PasswordSafe.java:28)
    at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.KeystoreStep.retrievePassword(KeystoreStep.java:96)
    at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.KeystoreStep.<init>(KeystoreStep.java:81)
    at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard.<init>(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:112)
    at org.jetbrains.android.actions.GenerateSignedApkAction.actionPerformed(GenerateSignedApkAction.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:237)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:321)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:911)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:136)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:311)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:130)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:130)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:521)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:48)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:541)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6541)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:646)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Also, when I run "gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace", it seems to have no errors while building:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 19s
26 actionable tasks: 26 up-to-date
```

Since I'm basically a beginner, I can't really read the error, but it seems to be related with the key, maybe? The problem is that I can't really change the key, since the "Build Signed APK" won't show up.

I'm trying to solve this for weeks by now.

Answer (score 1):

Got it fixed, the error was with the studio itself. Here's how I fixed in case someone get the same problem in the future: the only thing that got it fixed was by reseting the Studio settings, this can be done via deleting the configuration folder: [How to reset Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384033/how-to-reset-android-studio)