# How can I remove Android Studio Last Opened Project Record

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I want to remove the last opened project record from Android Studio, such that I can reach the normal welcome screen of Android Studio.

As my last opened project will cause complete hang to Android Studio, therefore I can't access to the Menu *Appearance & Behavior -> System Setting* disabling the reopen last project on startup.

Also, I didn't enable the command line launcher, open another project by command line cannot be done.

Please kindly assist.

Many Thanks!

Comment: try to reset android studio and see if it recovers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384033/how-to-reset-android-studio#19397632

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your android studio is crashed, and you can't do this from:

> File >> Settings >> Appearance & Behaviour >> System Settings >>
>   Reopen last project on startup checkbox

**For Windows, you can edit below file:**

> [SYSDRIVE]:\Users[USER-NAME]\.AndroidStudioX.X\config\options\ide.general.xml

Example:

> C:\Users\JohnDoe\.AndroidStudio3.3\config\options\ide.general.xml

Then add below option to it:

```
<option name="reopenLastProject" value="false" />
```

**Edit as advised by @Frank Fung from comments**
**For MAC**

> ~\Library\Preferences\AndroidStudioX.X/options/ide.general.xml

And the reopenLastProject options should add into the section of

```
<component name="GeneralSettings">
```

Comment: Thanks, i have checked the mac version, as i am using os x, to more specific, the location of the ide.general.xml for mac will be ~\Library\Preferences\AndroidStudioX.X/options/
And the reopenLastProject options should add into the section of  
<component name="GeneralSettings">

Comment: @FrankFung .. glad it helps .. modified the answer accordingly