# Autosuggestion of attributes in XML not working in android studio 3.3.2

Tags: android, android-studio

In layout XML files of Android Studio it usually shows suggestion of attributes for any component line 'layout_marginTop','layout_marginBottom' etc,

Now in my case it is not showing proper suggestions even though they are valid attributes.... it is happening in android studio 3.3.2

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried invalidating cache? I'm using the same build and it's working fine here.

Comment: You are getting suggestions, but it obviously can't predict you want 'margin' when you've only typed 'layout'. Does typing 'layout_m' not narrow it down to the relevant attributes? Because that list seems to be sorted alphabetically, which means layout_margin is rightly not at the top.

Comment: I agree with TheGamer007's comment - this should be a list sorted alphabetically and "app:layout..." is higher than "layout_..." - scroll down or type "layout_m" to get a better suggestion.

Comment: @bensadiku Your suggestion somehow helped me thank you

Comment: @TheGamer007 Even I after scrolling down I couldn't found that 'layout_margin' in the whole list. Now I got a solution for that, actually it is a problem related to andrid studio cache i just deleted .android3.3.2 folder from C->Users->''<username>" and restarted android studio.... Its working.....

Comment: This worked absolutely fine for me
[Reset Android Studio Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19397632/7708141)