# Why I cant open Android Studio after changing VMOptions

Tags: java, android-studio, android-emulator, jvm

Recently I changed the VMOptions on my Android Studio trying to free some RAM memory. Happens that I wrote and saved the command with an error and now I cant open Android Studio..

I tried to reinstall AS, delete studio64.vmoptions file at bin folder, but still cant open Android Studio. Can someone help me with that?

The studio.bat command clearly shows the error that i wrote in VMOptions, but I cant find and change that line
[Error in VMOptions that I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq26J.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing to this question: [How to reset Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384033/how-to-reset-android-studio)

**On Mac OS X**

Remove these directories:

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
~/.AndroidStudio*
```

**On Windows:**

Go to your User Folder - on Windows 7/8 this would be:

```
[SYSDRIVE]:\Users\[your username] (ex. C:\Users\JohnDoe\)
```

In this folder there should be a folder called .AndroidStudioBeta or .AndroidStudio (notice the period at the start - so on some OSes it would be hidden).

Delete this folder (or better yet, move it to a backup location - so you can return it if something goes wrong).

This should reset your Android Studio settings to default.

Comment: there is only (.android) folder - is it the same?

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to give you a long answer but there is a whole page about configuration so [here you go](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config).
Find the `.vmoptions` file and edit it.

The `.vmoptions` file located in the path:
C:\Users\yourPCuserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.2

Edit that file and change -Xms and -Xmx value like below:

**-Xms =256m**
**-Xmx=768m**

Comment: This is best answer. Just edit this file and put -Xms =256m  and -Xmx=768m. then it will work