# Android Studio Resource Manager not opening

Tags: android-studio, flutter, resourcemanager

I can't open the Resource Manager from Android Studio. It says "Waiting for the build to finish..." forever. I waited more than an hour but I still have the same issue --build never finishes.

How do I make sure build finishes?

[image: Always says "Waiting for the build to finish..."]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I Have tried many things but didn't work. Then I reset my android studio and now it's working.
For resetting,
[How to reset Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384033/how-to-reset-android-studio)