# Cant create android studio project after updating to 0.2.1

Tags: ubuntu, project, android-studio

Getting this message when trying to create new project after updating android to 0.2.1. in ubuntu 13.04:

Failed to import Gradle project: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':Testing'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':Testing'.
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':Testing:_DebugCompile'.
Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+.
Required by:
    TestingProject:Testing:unspecified

edit: im trying to create a Master/Detail Flow option instead of a Blank Activity. Haven't tried the other options

edit: ok using a blank activity option also gives the same error. 
It seems i need to redownload the full 0.2.1. version but i'm afraid of the current projects to stop working.

Comment: This solution seems to work for this version too:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17612960/382115

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely a problem with your Android SDK.

New updates to the Android SDK / Android Studio sometimes add extra required repos for SDK libraries.

By looking at your error message, it appears that you are missing the Android Support Repository:

[image: Android SDK Viewer Screen Shot]

When updating your Android SDK, also be sure that your are updating the correct SDK location. **Android Studio now ships with its own SDK copy already integrated**. If you are building from the commandline and also using Android Studio, **you may have two copies of the SDK** (one which is accessed via commandline and one which is accessed when building from Android Studio. Updating one of these will not automatically update the other.

Comment: Finally an answer which helped me... the fact that Android Studio ships its own SDK was unknown by me. I finally got it working, again.