# Gradle Error for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I'm trying out Android Studio on OS X and am running into a mysterious error message. I went through the [Google guide to building a simple UI](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html), but when I finished writing the XML file and hit Run in the IDE, I get the following message ("Test2" is the name of the project):

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':Test2:validateDebugSigning'.
> Could not find matching constructor for: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException(java.lang.String)
```

I have never developed an android app before, so I don't know how common this is. I did a search for this error and found no one encountering the same problem.

I tried the solution from [Abhan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586674/failed-to-import-new-gradle-project-in-android-studio/16620500#16620500) and I get a new error message:

```
Error: org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.settings.GradleSettings cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.settings.GradleSettings
```

Answer (score 0):

It warns you that android plug-in task validateDebugSigning cannot access the debug key. Check your accessibility to the debug.keystore.

On linux or OS X, the default location is ~/.android.  On windows, it's in C:\Documents and Settings\.android\ or C:\Users\.android.