# Initial build error on first project after installing Android Studio .2 on Mac Air

Tags: android, osx-lion, gradle, android-studio

I continue to get this error.  I have reinstalled Android Studio and even copied a functioning  installation from another user's Mac desktop without changing the result.  I am using OS X 10.7.5

Failed to import Gradle project: Cause: org.apache.commons.lang.ObjectUtils.compare(Ljava/lang/Comparable;Ljava/lang/Comparable;)I

I see others have had similar problems with Gradle but not with this error.

Comment: I think you should add some info on what you've tried to fix it. Have you tried installing Gradle through AS? As this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586674/failed-to-import-new-gradle-project-in-android-studio) suggests?

Comment: I went through the process of installing Gradle directly from Gradle as described in that answer and still get the same error.