# Unable to start Android Studio after installation

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to start Android Studio for the first time but getting error mentioned below

[image]

Could someone please let me know how to solve this error?

Comment: are you importing a project from eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your JAVA_HOME path, which will allow Android Studio to run. Have you done that?
Here is how to do that:

1. Right click your Computer icon, and click Properties
2. Windows 8 Users: Then click Advanced System settings to your left.
3. Now, go to the advanced tab, click Environment variables, under
   system variables, click New, and add a JAVA_HOME variable, it should
   look like [this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-X-6kU1Xa3N4/UZQjvlT5MoI/AAAAAAACXHg/fMkC4z6lABQ/s1600/java_home.PNG) (relative to your jdk version, if its the latest
   it should be identical).

If you already have that covered I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16620500/1182971) that can help you:

1. Go to your `AndroidStudio` directory where you installed your studio Like `D:\User\AndroidStudio`
2. In `AndroidStudio` go to `\AndroidStudio\plugins\gradle\lib` and copy `gradle.jar`
3. Paste this `gradle.jar` file to `\AndroidStudio\lib` directory.
4. Download gradle directly from [Gradle](http://services.gradle.org/distributions/)
5. Copy the contents of `gradle-1.7-bin.zip` - After extracting zip file - `(bin, media, init.d, lib folders)` to `\AndroidStudio\plugins\gradle`
6. Restart `AndroidStudio`

Comment: Dyna - Thank you for the help. After following above mentioned steps, error  "org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.settings.GradleSettings cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.settings.GradleSettings" was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#Troubleshooting

Scroll to the bottom.

Troubleshooting

Figure 1. Error dialog when opening an existing project.

Error: Gradle project refresh failed

Android Studio 0.2.0 has updated the Gradle plug-in to 0.5.0, which is not backwards compatible. When opening a project that uses an older version of the plug-in, Studio will display the error shown in figure 1 in the upper right corner of the IDE. To resolve the error, you must change the version of the Android Gradle plug-in to 0.5.0.

Click the link in the error dialog Search in build.gradle files. If the dialog is no longer visible, click Event Log  in the bottom-right corner of the IDE, then click Search in build.gradle files.
Double-click the line under the build.gradle usage. For example: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4. This opens the project build.gradle file.
Edit the classpath to change the gradle version to 0.5.+. For example:

```
dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I searched for task manager, opened it, went to more options, ended all background android studio tasks, and it worked.\

This happens because sometimes android studio does not fully close properly