# Android studio gradle deleted

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I accidentally deleted some gradle files from where i Android studio is installed. I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586674/failed-to-import-new-gradle-project-in-android-studio) tutorial to resolve another issue but it now even deleted some gradle files i cant even create a new project in Android studio. And cant build run or do anything. When i start android studio it shows me this error in following image:

[image]

If i open plugin manager it shows android support, cloud disabled like in this image:

[image]

In settings build tools it not does show gradle:

[image]

And in module settings it shows this:

[image]

Please someone guide me in this. I cant reinstall android studio, sdk and everything again as I have done many settings(installed plugins and git configs etc) in studio, so reinstalling everything is not an option. Any help?

Comment: try to install the gradle plugin, if not available ->
export all your settings, **File->Export Settings** for safety and then install (so don't delete current Version) Android Studio again, all your preferences and settings are stored separately, so they won't be overwritten and should be either used directly or asked to use when you start AndroidStudio again

Answer (score 1):

One non-technical solution is to install another instance of Android Studio at different location on your system. You can then compare the directories of where where you deleted the files and copy over the files that are not there in your original installation.

Comment: solution is to delete the .gradle folder from C:\Users\Username, restart android studio and then studio will install the fresh gradle version itself