# How to resolve Cannot load project: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException while opening previous projects

Tags: android, android-studio, runtimeexception

**Is anyone familiar with this error when loading the previous project**

[image: error dialog]

I am searching for a better solution to **re-open** the project instead of copying codes of each class.

I tried importing the same project but It's still showing this error in Event Log

```
10:35:05 AM Gradle sync started
10:35:29 AM Gradle sync failed: java.io.EOFException
10:35:29 AM Gradle sync completed
10:35:29 AM RuntimeException: Failed to set up Android modules in project 'MyProject': java.io.EOFException
```

*I have tried opening and importing project with Internet connection and in offline mode too. But same issue raised.*

Comment: Check your internet connection, or maybe try the offline mode.

Comment: I have already tried Disconnecting and Re-connecting the internet connection but still error raised.

Comment: Are the project files okay? Try browsing the project directory in question and see.

Comment: Yah bro it seems ok. But it prevented me to open any gradle files showing the same exception.

Comment: Just encountered same error. Restarting Android Studio resolved mine.

Answer (score 12):

Go to the `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin` folder.
Edit the file `idea.properties`, 
then add the line:

```
disable.android.first.run=true
```

and restart android.

Comment: It just saved me today. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Go to the **C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin folder**. Edit the file **idea.properties**, then add the line:

**disable.android.first.run=true** as the last line of your file. If any error occur then try running opening the file in editor in admin mode.

and restart android.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are using previous versions of **Gradle** update it with

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'` at your project level **build.gradle** & also check your Internet connection which causes blockage in downloading the required Jar's/Dependencies.

Comment: bro I am unable to open even a gradle file. When I clicked in it it shows `RuntimeException: Error building initial foldings: java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect header check`

Comment: Go through this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586674/failed-to-import-new-gradle-project-in-android-studio

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion but that is really a different issue. That didn't solve.